# New App Server ,DB server , intermittent Half second delay

Tags: .net, sql-server-2012, ado.net, iis-8

I have an intermittent performance problem on a new production environment. We have moved to a datacentre and have a new DB server and a new app server. When the problem starts some of my queries start running pretty much exactly a half second slower. All of my queries user stored procedures. Not all of them are affected by this problem but it is always the same subset. This issue tends to disappear after resetting my IIS application. All the queries run through the same data layer.
I have monitored the application pool on the app server using perfmon and it show no failures.
I have checked sys.dm_exec_query_stats on the DB and it shows the procs as running fast (tens of milliseconds).
Here is the code that runs all of the queries.

```
  Public Function ExecStoredProcCmd(ByVal SQLCmd As SqlCommand) As DataSet

    Dim daAdapter As New SqlDataAdapter(SQLCmd)
    Dim dsReturn As New DataSet
    Dim start As Date
    Try
        Dim c = GetOpenConnection()
        Using c
            Using SQLCmd
                SQLCmd.Connection = c
                SQLCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                '    PGF.Logging.LogMessage("cDataAccess.ExecStoredProcCmd " & SQLCmd.Connection.ConnectionString)
                start = Date.Now
                daAdapter.Fill(dsReturn)
                Return dsReturn
            End Using
        End Using
    Catch ex As Exception
        HandleError(ex)
        Throw
    Finally
        Dim ts = Date.Now - start
        If ts.TotalMilliseconds > 250 Then
            PGF.Logging.LogPerformance("ExecStoredProcCmd:" & SQLCmd.CommandText, ts.TotalMilliseconds, 1)
        End If
    End Try

End Function
```

Nothing ever gets logged that is under 490 milliseconds (and over 250).

What would cause stored procs that normally run in 10 to 20 milliseconds to take an extra half second?

Where should I look to find this error?

EDIT 
I have been comparing the sql profiler trace. In the test environment the slow proc has around 40 reads, zero writes.
In the prod environment, when the issue is occurring, the proc shows around 8 reads and zero writes for a duration of Zero! The big difference is in the audit logout times, the duration in prod is 506 which I guess is my problem as in test that shows as zero.

Here is the slow proc.

```
    SELECT cr.[CustomerRevisionID]
      ,cr.[CustomerID]
      ,cr.[ClientProducerRevisionID]
      ,c.FirstName CustomerFirstName
      ,c.MiddleName CustomerMiddleName
      ,c.LastName CustomerLastName
      ,c.CompanyName CustomerCompanyName
      ,c.contact CustomerCareOf
      ,Null CustomerRef
      ,1 CustomerNameFormat
      ,Null Verification
  FROM [dbo].[PGFT_CustomerRevision] cr
  JOIN PGF_External.Customer.CustomerMaster c on c.emscustomerID = cr.customerID
  WHERE [CustomerRevisionID] = @CustomerRevisionID
```

EDIT 2
I have noticed in the SQL server trace that when it is quick the procs are all executing on the same SPID, when it is slow they are different SPIDs

EDIT 3
When i query sys.sysprocesses when it is slow I see new rows being created for each query. Still don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had these exact same symptoms at a customer site. After much finger pointing with their infrastructure team, the issue turned out to be the VMWare bug that introduces a half-second network latency as detailed [in this article](https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2129176). Below is an excerpt from the kb article (emphasis mine):

Symptoms

You notice performance degradation for some client/servers workloads. 
Packets have up to a 0.5 second delay over the expected arrival in the application.

This issue is observed under these conditions:

- The guest operating system is Windows Server 2012, Windows 8 or later.
- The virtual machine is on hardware version 11/ ESXi 6.0 compatibility.
- The virtual NIC is vmxnet3 and the driver version is 1.6.6.0 and later.
- The Receive Side Coalescing (RSC) feature is enabled globally and on the vmxnet3 adapter.
- This issue is more prevalent when:

  - **Running Microsoft SQL/TDS based workloads**
  - Using Jumbo Frames
  - The client and server are on two different hosts

Cause

Depending on different physical NIC and workload characteristics like chipset, coalescing settings and packet inter arrival rate, some packets offloaded by RSC might experience an additional delay. When aggregating a number of packets, ESXi will only keep the Push Flag (PSH flag) if it was set on the first packet to be coalesced. If the first packet does not have the PSH flag set but subsequent packets do, the final coalesced packet will not have it set and as a result, might not be delivered to the application immediately.

Resolution

This issue is resolved in ESXi 6.0 Update 2, available at VMware Downloads.

Comment: I have passed this along to the server guys, fingers crossed.

Comment: Dan you are truly the man , I will sleep well tonight, thanks.

Comment: We did not patch the server (yet) The  Disable-NetAdapterRsc command worked.

Comment: @PatFromCanada, glad the Disable-NetAdapterRsc worked for you. Not the long term solution but much less painful than waiting half a second for each query.